# Macports: port install jpeg fails

Tags: macports, xcode, jpeg

History:

- installed MacPorts on Leopard
- upgraded to Snow Leopard
- uninstall all ports
- reinstalled XCode

  sudo port uninstall jpeg
  port info jpeg # returns jpeg @8a
  sudo port install jpeg

> DEBUG: Found port in file:///opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/graphics/jpeg
>   DEBUG: Changing to port directory: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/graphics/jpeg
>   DEBUG: OS Platform: darwin
>   DEBUG: OS Version: 10.3.0
>   DEBUG: Mac OS X Version: 10.6
>   DEBUG: System Arch: i386
>   DEBUG: setting option os.universal_supported to yes
>   DEBUG: org.macports.load registered provides 'load', a pre-existing procedure. Target override will not be provided
>   DEBUG: org.macports.unload registered provides 'unload', a pre-existing procedure. Target override will not be provided
>   DEBUG: org.macports.distfiles registered provides 'distfiles', a pre-existing procedure. Target override will not be provided
>   DEBUG: adding the default universal variant
>   DEBUG: Reading variant descriptions from /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/ports/_resources/port1.0/variant_descriptions.conf
>   DEBUG: Requested variant darwin is not provided by port jpeg.
>   DEBUG: Requested variant i386 is not provided by port jpeg.
>   DEBUG: Requested variant macosx is not provided by port jpeg.
>   --->  Computing dependencies for jpeg
>   DEBUG: Executing org.macports.main (jpeg)
>   DEBUG: Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (jpeg)
>   DEBUG: Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (jpeg)
>   DEBUG: Skipping completed org.macports.extract (jpeg)
>   DEBUG: Skipping completed org.macports.patch (jpeg)
>   --->  Configuring jpeg
>   DEBUG: Using compiler 'Mac OS X gcc 4.2'
>   DEBUG: Executing org.macports.configure (jpeg)
>   DEBUG: Environment: CFLAGS='-O2 -arch x86_64' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -arch x86_64' MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.6' CXX='/usr/bin/g++-4.2' F90FLAGS='-O2 -m64' LDFLAGS='-arch x86_64' OBJC='/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' FCFLAGS='-O2 -m64' INSTALL='/usr/bin/install -c' OBJCFLAGS='-O2 -arch x86_64' FFLAGS='-O2 -m64' CC='/usr/bin/gcc-4.2'
>   DEBUG: Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_graphics_jpeg/work/jpeg-8a" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local'
>   sh: line 0: cd: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_graphics_jpeg/work/jpeg-8a: No such file or directory
>   Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_graphics_jpeg/work/jpeg-8a" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local " returned error 1
>   DEBUG: Backtrace: configure failure: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_graphics_jpeg/work/jpeg-8a" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local " returned error 1
>       while executing
>   "$procedure $targetname" 
>   Warning: the following items did not execute (for jpeg): org.macports.activate org.macports.configure org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
>   Error: Status 1 encountered during processing.
>   To report a bug, see http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution when upgrading to a new major version of OS X is to:

1. Save a list of ports.
2. Completely uninstall MacPorts (maybe even delete `/opt/local`).
3. Install the new Xcode.
4. Reinstall MacPorts using the latest DMG
5. Reinstall ports that you had installed earlier.

In your case, I'm not sure if you installed the latest MacPorts after upgrading to Snow Leopard. Hopefully this works. More details can be found at the [MacPorts wiki](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration).

Comment: thanks a lot, this did the trick.
To uninstall MacPorts I followed there instructions:
http://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling